# Visual Studio 2019 Visual Basic Windows Form Application add WPF documentviewer to toolbox, documentviewer not in toolbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYWIY.jpg)I can't get WPF documentviewer to show up in the Visual Studio 2019 toolbox. Is this not compatible or obsolete? Is there a similar add in?

Dialog says "the following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but were not enabled in the active designer" and "Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .Net framework version"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zPQq.png)

Comment: Any information about when the problem's firstly occurred? Because VS 2019 might have bugs too.

Comment: Hadn't tried to use the WPF documentviwer previously, so I do not know. Do I need to add a reference?

Comment: [ElementHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost);k(VS.Toolbox);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.create a VB winFroms project named VBWinForms

2.add a WPF userControl named VBWPFDocumentViewer, and add DocumentViewer in Grid in xaml

```
<Grid><DocumentViewer></DocumentViewer></Grid>
```

3.Build your project, and the usercontrol(VBWPFDocumentViewer) will be shown in ToolBox
[image]

4.add the VBWPFDocumentViewer in Form1.vb

You can also use ElementHost to load the DocumentViewer,here is the step:

1.project named VBWinForms, and add a WPF userControl named VBWPFDocumentViewer

2.add the ElementHost and event Form1_Load for the Form1.vb[Design],add code in Form1.vb like below:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim host As ElementHost = New ElementHost()
    host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Dim uc As VBWinForms.VBWPFDocumentViewer = New VBWinForms.VBWPFDocumentViewer()
    host.Child = uc
    Controls.Add(host)
End Sub
```

3.run the project to show the documentViewer